# Moving an index which underlies a PK constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints, alter-table

SQL Server 2012 SP3

I've got a table with a clustered unique index which I want to move to the SECONDARY filegroup.

The standard method is to `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT` and then `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` it back again in the new filegroup.  However, there's a chain of FKs which I'd have to drop and recreate.

Is there any other way to move the underlying data without lots of drops?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) to move the primary key index to a different filegroup. This will also avoid the sort.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable(YourPrimaryKeyColumn)
    WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)
    ON [YourSecondaryFileGroup];
```

Comment: How do you add another *clustered* index to a table that already has unique clustered index (automatically built by the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` statement)?  And that would mean that there are two identical indexes on the same column as the PK constraint.